# How to change Info.plist in a signed package?

Tags: macos, code-signing, info-plist

The team needs to change Info.plist to test certain features. 
But sometimes the app (very) silently crashes.

```
System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1
```

Now, if we test the signature as recommended [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2318/_index.html):

`codesign --verify -vvvv -R='anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] exists and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] exists or certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] exists)'` < path to app >
or
`spctl --verbose --assess` < path to app >

```
< path to app >: invalid Info.plist (plist or signature have been modified)
```

Ok, but I really want to modify it:

- changing SIP is not an option
- re-sign only Info.plist is acceptable, but how ?

So two questions:

1. How can we change Info.plist ?
2. (optional) When the system validates it ? After restart maybe ?

The question has an answer, in the brotherhood: https://superuser.com/questions/961797/how-to-change-info-plist-in-a-signed-package .

Comment: you cannot change files in the sealed bundle randomly... they are all hashed and singed off during archiving – you can test it via setting up a test environment, or test units, etc... every time you archive the project, all files (incl. `info.plist`) will be signed off again in the new bundle.

Comment: "setting up a test environment" - how ? It is preferable to test the user's exact environment, not some other thing. Yes, we could configure the Info.plist before making the setup, but unfortunately it is not the case right now. There must be a more simple solution (except of adding a `debug.settings.plist` somewhere).

Comment: We need more information about the context. Is this for internal (within your company) testing? Does it have to be signed with a valid developer ID, or an you use a development or self-signed ID? How extensive are the changes to the Info.plist (i.e. would it be possible to have a list of pre-built Info.plist files, and a list if signatures to swap in along with them)?

Comment: It is for internal testing, not for the outside world. We have a valid developer ID ... but anything accepted by Apple (for internal testing) is fine. The changes are rather extensive (strings, URL names).

Comment: @Liviu, e.g. you'd create a separated archive with the _test_ `info.plist` file, if that test passed and everything was alright then you can switch back to the _live_ `info.plist` file and submit the project to your end-users... you could do so by e.g. setting up different targets for the same project and use those targets to build the right archive for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Re-signing the application can be very fast:

```
codesign --force --verbose=4 --sign "Developer ID Application: <your name> (<team ID>)" <application>
```

The trick is to avoid the `--deep` option. On my High Sierra it takes about 20 seconds.

Comment: In my case the string passed to `--sign` was simply the email address of the "Creator" of the app development certs. You might need to create a new one in Xcode, then click on "Manage Certificates...".